# Cannot read file #{Rails.root}/RubymineProjects/project2/public/system/resumes/attach_files/1/original/guide.pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, sendfile

i uploaded a pdf file during create a new employee in employeeController but after saving this .i want to download file from show.html.erb by clicking on name of file.
**show.html.erb**

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Resume:</b></td>
    <td><%=link_to @employee.resume.attach_file_file_name ,download_employee_path(@employee)  ,:class=> "btn btn-link" %></td>
  </tr>
```

and my method to download file is defined in employee controller.

**EmployeeController.rb**

```
def download
    @resume = Resume.where(:employee_id=> params[:id] ).first
    file_path = @resume.attach_file_file_name
    if !file_path.nil?
      send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/system/resumes/attach_files/#{@resume.id}/original/#{file_path}", :X_SendFile => true, :disposition => 'attachment'
    else
      redirect_to profile_url
    end
  end
```

resume is another table in database. 
**Association:** `employee has_one resume`.

but it does not work.the error is

> Cannot read file /RubymineProjects/project2/public/system/resumes/attach_files/1/original/guide.pdf

Comment: Have you checked that `guide.pdf` is present by following `/RubymineProjects/project2/public/system/resumes/attach_files/1/original/guide.pdf` in your project directory ?

Comment: Well i use  **send_file @resume.attach_file.path** instead of defining path like that **send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/system/resumes/attach_files/#{@resume.id}/original/#{file_path}", :X_SendFile => true, :disposition => 'attachment' ** in download action of **Employee_Controller.rb**

Comment: Still you getting that problem ? or resolved by using `@resume.attach_file.path`  !!

Comment: its resolved by @resume.attach_file.path